# How to fix live usb unsupported resolution

Tags: live-usb

I have an old monitor with resolution only up to 1440x900, when i tried ubuntu 20.04 the screen shows an image unsupported resolution and no additional changes.

To rule out bad live usb i used ruffus and Universal USB Installer

Comment: I would have ruled out a bad image on the usb via validation on another device, I don't think two writes rules out a invalid media, esp. given you haven't mentioned ISO validation, and even then I'd not rule it out.

Comment: I will take a look at that

Comment: @guiverc Well tested and it works on my two laptops with resolution 1376x768

Comment: Works with safe graphics options